# I'm working on this beginner project and i'm getting error

Tags: python

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.name= restaurant_name
        self.cuisine = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + ' serves ' + self.cuisine + ' food.')

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + ' is now open. \nCome and Have some delicious ' +self.cuisine+ ' food.' )

restaurant= Restaurant('Big Chillo', 'Italian')
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()

class cuisine(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, cuisine_type):
        self.name = cuisine_type

        super().__init__(cuisine_type)

    def availability(self):
        print ('These are the available cuisines ' + self.name.title())

menu =cuisine['Tiramisu \nCannoli \nPanna \ncotta \nCassata \nSemifreddo']
menu.availability()
```

File "D:/python project/restaurant.py", line 25, in 
Come and Have some delicious Italian food.
    menu =cuisine['Tiramisu \nCannoli \nPanna \ncotta \nCassata \nSemifreddo']
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What's `cuisine[...]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Its supposed to give me a list of the available cuisine_types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 3 issues with your code:
1. As mention by @FHTMitchell, Call functions / class constructors using parentheses () rather than square brackets []
2. You do not have Restaurant Constructor with 1 argument so I added extra parameter to code `super().__init__("RestaurantName",cuisine_type)`
3. `self.name` is String so we should not call it as a function in print of availability method changed `self.name()` to `self.name`

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.name= restaurant_name
        self.cuisine = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + ' serves ' + self.cuisine + ' food.')

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + ' is now open. \nCome and Have some delicious ' +self.cuisine+ ' food.' )

restaurant= Restaurant('Big Chillo', 'Italian')
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()

class cuisine(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, cuisine_type):
        self.name = cuisine_type

        super().__init__("hello",cuisine_type)

    def availability(self):
        print ('These are the available cuisines ' + self.name)

menu =cuisine('Tiramisu \nCannoli \nPanna \ncotta \nCassata \nSemifreddo')
menu.availability()
menu.describe_restaurant()
```

The output I got is:

> ```
> Big Chillo serves Italian food.   
> Big Chillo is now open.  
> Come and Have some delicious Italian food.  
> These are the available cuisines hello
> Hello serves Tiramisu 
> Cannoli 
> Panna 
> cotta 
> Cassata 
> Semifreddo food.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Call functions / class constructors using parentheses `()` rather than square brackets `[]`

```
menu = cuisine('Tiramisu \nCannoli \nPanna \ncotta \nCassata \nSemifreddo')
```

Comment: I have changed but still getting error  [File "D:/python project/restaurant.py", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(cuisine_type)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cuisine_type']

Comment: That's because `Restaurant.__init__` takes two arguments `restaurant_name, cuisine_type`. You've only passed one (via `super`).